# Google Analytics Custom Dimension Page View

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following working code and I wanted to see the the console log of the page view for each custom dimension I have.

```
var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
  query: {
    'ids': 'ga:XXXXXX',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
    'dimensions': 'ga:dimension1',
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
  }
});

// Runs the query.
report.execute();

// Specifies the callback function  to be run when the query succeeds.
report.on('success', function(response) {

  // Logs the entire response object.
  console.log(response);

  // Logs just the total pageviews.
  console.log(response.totalsForAllResults['ga:pageviews']);
});
```

Comment: @Rob M.
Thanks for editing the format of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to do multiple queries to get these counts. Since dimensions can overlap (e.g. `ga:browser=Chrome` and `ga:date=20150821`) or not overlap (e.g. `ga:browser=Internet Explorer` and `ga:operatingSystem=Windows`), it would be much more complicated to parse the result and tally the counts yourself. Just do a separate query for each dimension you have.

Here's an example:

```
var baseQueryData = {
  'ids': 'ga:XXXXXX',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
  'start-date': '7daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
}

function runQuery(dimension, callback) {
  var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: baseQueryData});
  report.set({query: {dimensions: dimension}});
  report.on('success', callback);
  report.execute();
}

function logResult(response) {
  var dimension = response.query.dimensions;
  var count = response.totalsForAllResults['ga:pageviews'];
  console.log(dimension, count);
}

runQuery('ga:dimension1', logResult);
runQuery('ga:dimension2', logResult);
runQuery('ga:dimension3', logResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as usual, for your quite smart code. But, what I wanted to do was, what if I have one custom dimension (dimension1, for instance) and I have like 10 different values of dimension1. How do I see the log for each one of them?

Comment: If you know what the value is, you can add a filter to the query, something like `{filter: 'ga:dimension1==someValue'}`. If you don't know what the value is, then you can iterate through `response.rows` and get those values.

Comment: If you just log the `response` object, you can inspect it in your browser's developer tools, and that should tell you what you need to do.

Comment: How do you use the response.rows ?

Comment: @AhaduMelesse at this point you're asking some relatively basic web development and JavaScript questions that no longer have much to do with Google Analytics. I'd suggest taking some time to learn basic JavaScript programming concepts, and then I think a lot of this will make much more sense to you.

Comment: I was trying different approaches and none of them were working, I will work on it more and I will let you know what I am up to.
Thanks.